# Doubts about this summation (Geometric series)

Tags: summation, geometric-series

[image]

[image: I´m using this quote]

I don´t understand why does in the numerator is $e^{{t}/{2}}$

Comment: Geometric series.

Comment: "The key parts of your question should not be in an embedded image such as a photo/screenshot/etc., such images are not searchable, they are not accessible to those using screen readers, and they don't show up in question summaries." -https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992 . For a new user, I recommend reading through the provided link, and learning how to use MathJax to type your questions.

Comment: Thanks, I´m sorry, I´m new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} ar^{n-1}=a\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} r^{n}=a\frac 1 {1-r}$ for $|r|<1$. Now multiply both sides by $r$ to get $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} ar^{n}=a\frac r {1-r}$.

Comment: I made some edits to my questions, look please

Comment: I´m using the fact of the second image, but I don´t get it

Comment: @rositagalixx I have edited my answer.  All you have to do is multiply both sides be $r$ in solution 1.9.2.